# django-autocomplete-light: "The results could not be loaded"

Tags: jquery, python, django, autocomplete, jquery-select2

I'm developing a small project in Django and I would like to use the **django-autocomplete-light plugin** in a specific admin form field. I'm following this simple tutorial: [link](http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.org/en/master/tutorial.html)

The autocomplete field has been populated but when I start searching it prompt "*The results could not be loaded*".

I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to jpic, using FireBug I've found that the error was "Cannot resolve keyword 'name'".

I solved adding `related_name='name'` to the model's foreignkey involved in this autocomplete thing.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the first thing to check is your view. Opening firebug or webkit inspector on the Network tab displays the network requests. The autocomplete request should be visible here: try to open it manually, play with the GET parameters and see if it works as expected.

If it does, again in the inspector, in the Scripts tab, place a breakpoint in the [processResults function](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light/blob/47db6f0fb86cb7052c2b1b7e3773a45a0a040cec/src/dal_select2/static/autocomplete_light/select2.js#L40-L47) and ensure that it returns the proper data for select2.

Comment: That's help me a lot: I've found this error: "Cannot resolve keyword 'name' into field. Choices are: brand, brand_id, chassis_number ... ". My model hasn't any 'name' attribute!